# Customized look on first login

Tags: spring, web-applications, contextpath

I'm working on a java Spring webapp. There is requirement that each user will have possibility to customize the webapp look & feel. I'd like if the user will see the customized look, even on his first login. How would you do that?

My ideas are for the time being

- multiple contexts(per customer), but it is not dynamic
- send user a link with some attribute, then set the custom info to cookies
- in Spring I can possibly create some path variable (`@RequestMapping(value = "/{customerId}/login")`)
- just create universal login page, which will be not customizable

How would you achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to offer customized looks to every user, you can use use [Portlets](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/09/14/what-is-a-portlet.html). Spring also supports Portlet development.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the technology stack is set. I would need to customize the portal anyway. The main problem is how to show customization before login(i.e. customer company logo)

Answer (score 0):

You can give separate URLs to each user, could be using sub-domain or url parameters. Then fetch the request URL in your handling page to deliver specific look-n-feel.

You could also try to explore [GrooveUI](https://www.grooveui.com), which is a third party tool that allows you to define website theme based on access URL.